# How to adjust height of Kendo().DropDownList() popup portion?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have kendo dropdown list in my mvc application and need to adjust height of the list portion of the control (the piece that consists of option to choose). I tried adding height property within my htmlAttributes, but it grabs fixed-size portion of the page underneath the control before it is even clicked.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                    .Name("My Dropdown List")
                    .Value(Model.xxx)
                    .DataTextField("MYDESCRIPTIEN")
                    .DataValueField("MYFIELD")
                    .DataSource(mydatasource);
                    })
                    .Events(e => e.Change("onMyChange"))
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
                )
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A height style in the HtmlAttributes will be applied to the widget wrapper. Use the Height fluent method instead:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
   .Height(50)
)
```